# Check an number in an array is a powers number

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

How to check which number is a power in this array?
`arr = [16, 32, 72, 96]`

output: `[16, 32]` because `16 = 4^2` and `32 = 2^5`

It's not a solution about power of 2, it's about power of n.

This is my actual code :

```js
let array1 = [16, 32, 72];
function findPowofNum(array1) {
    // var result = [];
    if (array1.length == 1)
        return true;
    for(let i = 2; i * i <= array1.length; i++) {
       let value = Math.log(array1/length) / Math.log(i);
       if((value - Math.floor(value)) < 0.00000001)
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(findPowofNum(array1));
```

Can you give me a example for this solution by javascript?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: let array1 = [16, 32, 72];
function findPowofNum(array1) {
    // var result = [];
    if (array1.length == 1)
    return true;

    for(let i = 2; i * i <= array1.length; i++) {
        let value = Math.log(array1/length) / Math.log(i);
        if((value - Math.floor(value)) < 0.00000001)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(array1);

Comment: It would help to include a case/requirement for `3^3 == 27`, since powers of 4 are covered as a subset of powers of two, which btw is easily checked as `x != 0 && (x & (x-1)) == 0`

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking. My guess is: *write a function of one argument, an array of integers, to return true if at least one integer in the array is a non-trivial power of an integer, otherwise return false*. Can you confirm or correct this guess.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
arr = [16, 32, 72, 96].filter(
    value => Number.isInteger(Math.log2(value))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but I need to check is not power of 2, it's power of n like 4^2.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom boolean function to iterate through the elements and append to an empty array as you check like this..

```
function isPowerofTwo(n){
       return (Math.ceil((Math.log(n) / Math.log(2))))
            == (Math.floor(((Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)))));
}
let arr= [16, 32, 72, 96];
let values=[]
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 if(isPowerofTwo(arr[i])){
   values.push(arr[i]);
   }
}
console.log(values);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but I need to check is not power of 2, it's power of n like 4^2

Answer (score 1):

```js
const numbers = [16, 32, 72, 96];
const power = numbers.filter(isPowerOfTwo);
function isPowerOfTwo(n)
{
  if (n == 0)
    return 0;
  while (n != 1)
  {
    if (n%2 != 0)
      return 0;
    n = n/2;
  }
  return 1;
}

console.log(power);
```

To know more about this visit
visit: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-whether-a-given-number-is-power-of-2/

Comment: Thank you for your time but I need to check that is not power of 2, it's power of n like 4^2

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please, can you format your answer to be more readable using the tools provide by stackoverflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score -1):

I think it is 2^4 not 4^2 and what I believe is you want to check if the number is and root of 2 or not
Solution

```
   let arr=[16,32,72,96];
let i=1;
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){       // this loop will run up to 2^10
let k=Math.pow(2,i);if(k==arr[i-1]){
//do whatever you want to do with the number
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but I need to check is not power of 2, it's power of n like 4^2

Answer (score -1):

This will return true if at least one element y of the array is equal to base<sup>power</sup>, where base and power are integers.

The basic idea is to simply try each possible base, compute the value of power needed to make base<sup>power</sup> equal to the value, and check to see if power is very close to an integer.

This code only works for positive values, and probably won't work for for value in the upper range near Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, though I really haven't tested it.

```js
let array1 = [7, 13, 72, 27];

function isPowOfNum(val) {
    // smallest base is 2, largest is sqrt(val)

    for (let base=2; base <= Math.sqrt(val); base++) {
        // if val = base ** x then log(val) = x * log(base), x = log(val) / log(base)
        // and x is an integer
        let power = Math.log(val) / Math.log(base);
        if (Math.abs(power - Math.round(power)) < 0.000001) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function findPowofNum(array1) {
    if (array1.length === 1)
        return true;
    return array1.some(isPowOfNum);
}

console.log(findPowofNum(array1));
```